# Angular.js output value live on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-click

I'm new to angular and little bit confused with it. So basically I created a simple button and i want to run function `foo()` whitch assigns variable `var one = 1;` to `$scope` and outputs it in `<p>{{one}}<p>` every time its clicked like in live typing but this seems not working. Please provide me a solution to this.

```
<html ng-app="app">
 <!-- Body tag augmented with ngController directive  -->
 <body ng-controller="myController">
   <input type="text" ng-model="name">
   <p>{{name}}</p>
   <p>{{one}}</p>

   <button ng-click="foo()">1</button>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="controller.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope',function($scope){
  var one = 1;

  $scope.name = name;

  function foo(){
    return $scope.one = one;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Provide jsfiddle or working code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

function foo() dont exist in $scope your controller "myController"

if you declaration:

$scope.foo = function(){}

in your controller, then this work for you

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling controller function from the html, controller function should be scope. Other wise  `ng-click` directive doesn't recognize the function.

same concept goes to binding variable to html. only scope variables can directly bind to html using curly brackets. so inside foo function `var on`e should assign to `scope.one` in order to display it in the html.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

 var one = 1;
 

  $scope.name = name;
  
  $scope.foo = function(){
      $scope.one = one;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
   <p>{{name}}</p>
   <p>{{one}}</p>

   <button ng-click="foo()">1</button>
</div>
```